# Symfony-Disabling specific field validations from controller

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 2.7.6. I have created an entity called employee and its interactive forms are generated using doctrine crud generator. Entity have the following fields

```
 1. id
 2. firstname
 3. lastname
 4. email
 5. username
 6. password
```

**validations are working as expected from user registration form for all the fields.**

**ISSUE: I have created a login form and i want to suppress validation for the fields firstname, lastname and email and exclude these elements from rendering on my page**

I have modified my controller like this for rendering my form

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('XXXEmployeeBundle:Employee');
    $form = $this->createForm(new \XXX\EmployeeBundle\Form\EmployeeType(), $entity, array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_login'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            ));
            $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));
            $form->remove('firstname');
    $form->remove('lastname');
    $form->remove('email');
            $form->handleRequest($request);
```

**This works fine when the from is rendering as the fields are excluded from the form. But my $form->isvalid() is returning false. As I have printed the errors using $form->getErrorsAsString() method, its showing like:**

firstname: ERROR: First name cannot be empty. lastname: ERROR: Last name code cannot be empty. employeeFirstName: ERROR: Employee first name cannot be empty. email: ERROR: Email cannot be empty.

Is this the right method to achieve this functionality?? Please help me in solving the issue. Thanks

Comment: i sugges you to use the validation-groups take a look at the doc here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups

Comment: As suggested, validation groups can be used but, in my humble opinion, trying to make multi-use forms is more trouble than it's worth.  Especially for simple stuff.  Just make a login form and don't try to reuse a registration form.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity you mush include nullable=true like this

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $nombre;
```

And telling doctrine that is nullable, neither backend/frontend check the value.

Greetings !

Comment: Not resolved :-( Still the same issue. In my case none of the fields are nullable

Comment: can anyone help me in solving this??

Comment: The perfect solution is adding groups={"login"} in Assert attribute. Then you have to create frorm from controller like this $form = $this->createForm(new \XXX\EmployeeBundle\Form\EmployeeBasicInfoType, $entity, array(
            'validation_groups' => 'login',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_myinfo_personal'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

Comment: /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $nombre; this piece of code doesnt make sense

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in logic.

1. When you create registration form - you want to create and save new
   entity.
2. When you create login form - you want to compare login and
   password between form and entity.

So. You should create special form class for login (not from registration) and don't set data-enitity (second parameter in createForm function)

And, please check if you have the same form object in controller action that handles this form.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a work around
Get all form's errors within your controller by

```
$form->getErrors()
```

and then loop over them, if it's the error you know it would happen, just bypass it on purpose and process further.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) { // remove $form->isValid() check
    foreach($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        // check if it's expected error, then do nothing and proceed further for user 
        // if it's unexpected throw an exception, catch them below and add error message to session flashbag. or something similar
    }
}
```